# style not applied with javascript :-( But... Console shows

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, styles

I apply a style using jQuery

```
$("#notifPrefWA").attr('style', "border-radius: 5px; border:#FF0000 5px solid; padding: 10px;");
```

& it does take effect: at least on the source and on the console when inspected in Chrome... but the color simply doesn't show up.

Any ideas? This is confusing. No javascript errors. The element ID is unique in the HTML

[image: screenshot of html, console, and inspected]

Answer (score 4):

The issue is because you cannot put a border on a checkbox. If you need to do that, wrap it in another element, such as a `span` and put the border on that:

```css
span.checkbox-container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: #FF0000 5px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<span class="checkbox-container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="notifPrefWA" />
</span>
```

As an aside, if you're going to set CSS properties on an element using jQuery, use the `css()` method, *not* `attr('style')`.

Comment: I'll gladly revisit the answer if you can explain why you feel this is wrong.

Comment: Super.. thanks a ton. Worked for me. Use attr to apply style using javascript! As an aside, the console really shouldn't show it if I apply it directly on the checkbox. A new feature for Chrome (if not a bug report). Ah Well...